# Java Selenium 3.14 and Edge Chromium - How to get to work?

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, microsoft-edge

I've been trying to get Java Selenium 3.14 to work with Edge Chromium, to no avail. i came across the Microsoft Edge Selenium Tools (https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Edge.SeleniumTools/3.141.0) but it's a .net tool.

Any guidance for a Java implementation?

thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you want to automate Edge Chromium using Selenium WebDriver in Java? You could follow the below steps:

- Download the WebDriver language binding of your choice from [this page](https://www.selenium.dev/downloads/) (in your case it should be Selenium Java 3.141.59).
- Download the matching version of Microsoft Edge WebDriver from [this page](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/tools/webdriver/#downloads) (the same version with your Edge Browser).
- Sample code (change the path in the code to your owns):

```
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver; 
import org.openqa.selenium.edge.EdgeDriver; 
import org.openqa.selenium.edge.EdgeOptions; 


public class Edgeauto { 
    public static void main(String[] args) {  
        System.setProperty("webdriver.edge.driver", "your\\path\\to\\edge\\webdriver\\msedgedriver.exe"); 
        EdgeOptions edgeOptions = new EdgeOptions();         
        WebDriver driver = new EdgeDriver(edgeOptions); 
        driver.get("https://www.google.com/"); 
     } 
}
```

Comment: Embarrasingly simple. I was mislead by this page https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/webdriver-chromium and skipped the simple approach... Thanks.

Comment: It opens the edge browser but it keeps on loading indefinitely. Any idea how to resolve this?